# Problems with layer-selector code on joomla article

Tags: carto, joomla

I have three visualizations I have created,you can see them separately on the following links
http://www.locattivitaecon.altervista.org/index.php/mineral-deposits-map
http://www.locattivitaecon.altervista.org/index.php/roads-port-airport-population-map
http://www.locattivitaecon.altervista.org/index.php/countries-regions-provinces-map
Now I want to create only one map with all the layers of the previous maps and to be able to select the maps separately. I have written the following code searching for different examples but I don't know what to write on the part where I put *. Any ideas?

```
<div id="map" style="width: 1150px; height: 800px; background: white;"> </div>
<div id="layer_selector" class="cartodb-infobox">
<ul>
<li id="abc" class="selected">All</li>
<li id="efg">Places</li>
<li id="hij">Cables</li>
</ul>
</div>
<script>// <![CDATA[
var selectedLayer;
      // create layer selector
      function createSelector(layers) {

        var $options = $('#layer_selector li');
        $options.click(function(e) {
          // get the area of the selected layer
          var $li = $(e.target);
          var layer = $li.attr('id');
          if(selectedLayer != layer ){
            // definitely more elegant ways to do this, but went for
            // ease of understanding
            *if (layer == 'abc'){
            *}
            *else if (layer == 'efg') {
            *}
            *else {
            }*
          }
        });
      }

      var layerN = {};
      function main() {
        var map = L.map('map', { 
          zoomControl: true,
          center: [20, 20],
          zoom: 5
        });
        // get the currently selected style
        selectedStyle = $('li.selected').attr('id');

        var url1 = 'http://obiettivolaurea.cartodb.com/api/v2/viz/39521542-53a2-11e4-85f3-0e018d66dc29/viz.json';
          var url2 = 'http://narusegawa.cartodb.com/api/v2/viz/881d54ec-4359-11e4-818b-0e10bcd91c2b/viz.json';
          var url3='http://tsubaki.cartodb.com/api/v2/viz/4a9159ca-467e-11e4-80a0-0e4fddd5de28/viz.json'

          cartodb.createLayer(map, url1)
            .addTo(map) // ultimately not displayed
            .done(function (layers) {
                createSelector(layers);
                cartodb.createLayer(map, url2)
                .addTo(map) // displays OK
                .done(function (layers) {
                    createSelector(layers);
                    cartodb.createLayer(map, url3)
                    .addTo(map) // displays OK
                    .done(function (layers) {
                         createSelector(layers);
                     })
                     .error(function (){
                          console.log('problem adding 2nd layer');
                      });
                     })
                .error(function (){
                    console.log('problem adding 2nd layer');
                });
            })
            .error(function () {
                console.log('There is something wrong with requested data!');
            });

      }
      window.onload = main;
// ]]></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Following links could be helpful:

http://bl.ocks.org/andrewxhill/10506396

http://bl.ocks.org/xavijam/663aec5349fd80f79195

Comment: This is a links only answer which would be more helpful to readers if accompanied by a brief description of what is to be found at each link.